# How to tell if a mobile page was designed specifically for mobile?

Tags: mobile

Is there a way to tell if a mobile page you've downloaded is just a desktop page modified with media queries, or is a separate page designed specifically for mobile? I'd like to go through a list of the "20 Best Mobile Pages" and see what percent were designed specially for mobile.

Comment: Why the downgrade?

Comment: Do not know why the down vote, but it is an option to download each sources with different `user-agent` and check if those are actually the same. (You can check as well the used CSS files to get a better hint on those, but I do not know 100% solution to this.)

Comment: Just a thought: 
A nontechnical way would be to contact the "20 Best Mobile Pages" and ask them how they created their sites. Usually people like to talk about their work. It's timeconsuming but could be interesting.

Comment: Usually the websites that have an "m" in front of the URL like m.websitename.com, are usually those that have a separate website for mobile. I used to work on a well known website for a company that had a separate mobile version.

Comment: You'd have to pull up the CSS and look at the media queries...there is no other separate page for this. @RocketRisa is also correct...there are some subdomains that are specifically for mobile sites, but again, you would see this reflected in the CSS.

Answer (score 2):

Let me express my understanding on your task:
You want to check whether one webpage, e.g. https://www.google.com, is designed for both mobile device and desktop computer(it means the two types visit could cause server deliver different webpage), or just for mobile device or just for desktop.

If my understanding is right, the following is my answer:

You could change the "user agent" in your http request, then analyze whether you could get the same or different content from the same URL. About the "user agent", more explanation is here:
https://www.thoughtco.com/detecting-hits-from-mobile-devices-3469093

After you get the contents from different "user agent" settings in your http requests, then if the mobile device's type "user agent" content is different from the desktop's type "user agent" content, then you could assume that URL page is specially designed for a mobile device.

But because there is no special international standard to tell the client whether the content is for mobile or for desktop computer, so it's your job to make this decision after you get the same HTML content from both mobile device "user agent" and desktop "user agent" settings.

Answer (score 1):

Google has a test specifically for this problem, it has API using REST, it can be used with Go,Java, Javascript, PHP, Python and Ruby:

https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/search-console-api/

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Go on the site on desktop, then use Chrome's inspect element to test a mobile sized browser. Then go on your phone and go to the site. If the results are different, then it was designed for mobile, if not then the website was just built to be responsive.